# stuffing values from json in a html string (in form elements) and making them readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a HTML string like this:

```
<h5><span class="wp-step">Step 1 : </span> Service Info</h5><div class="wp-details"><h2>Procedure includes:</h2>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Procedure Includes" value="Microdermabrasion">Microdermabrasion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Procedure Includes" value="Chemical Peels">Chemical Peels<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Procedure Includes" value="Botox">Botox<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Procedure Includes" value="Fillers">Fillers<br>
</p>


<h2>Customized For:</h2>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Customized For" value="For oily and combination skin">For oily and combination skin<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Customized For" value="For normal, dry skin">For normal, dry skin<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Customized For" value="For sensitive skin">For sensitive skin<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Customized For" value="For dull�visibly ageing skin">For dull�visibly ageing skin<br>
</p>



<h2>Duration of this procedure (including the preparation time)</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="Procedure Duration" value="0-30 mins">0-30 mins<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Procedure Duration" value="30-60 mins">30-60 mins<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Procedure Duration" value="60-90 mins">60-90 mins<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Procedure Duration" value="More than 90 mins">More than 90 mins<br>





<h2>What are the known possible side effects?</h2>
<p>
<textarea id="Side Effects" name="Side Effects" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
</p>


<h2>Any other details or restrictions to add?</h2>
<p>
<textarea id="More Details" name="More Details" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
</p>
```

Secondly I have a json in the format:

```
    {Procedure Includes: "Microdermabrasion",
 Customized For: "For oily and combination skin",
 Procedure Duration: "0-30 mins",
 Side Effects: "test",
 More Details: "test"}
```

Now I need to convert this string to a read only html string with respective values stuffed. Respective checkboxes should be checked and so as radio buttons and textareas etc.

I have tried several loops but all are getting too complex. Is there a standard approach to handle this?

Comment: That's not valid JSON (nor object)! BTW, what have you tried?

Comment: If you think its not because of "", then assume that they are present. In fact they are. I have copy pasted from console. I have tried using find method of jquery to extract all input and set there respective values. Got stuck at re-constructing the whole string. I then tried looping through the string but then it became very cumbersome to identify form elements!

Comment: read only html string?

Comment: all the form fields like input,textarea etc in the string should become readonly

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON and then loop through the object, then loop through each field that has multiple inputs and check the according inputs, and then put the data in the fields with just one `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

```
var json; //Get the JSON somehow...
var info = JSON.parse(json); //...and parse it.

var procedureForm; //Our form
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { //When the window loads...
    //Set procedureForm

    for (var name in info) { //Loop through the object

        //If the field with this name is a bunch of inputs...
        if (procedureForm[name].hasOwnProperty("length")) {
                //Loop through it...
                //If the input value matches, check the input
            }
        }

        //Otherwise...
        else {
            //Just put the data into the input/textarea 
            procedureForm[name].value = info[name];
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NobleMushtak/P3v9Y/1/

Comment: and how do i handle the nested objects in case of checkboxes?

Comment: Use an array to handle more than one checkboxes in a field: http://devdoodle.net/dev/163/